Как загрузить файл SQL в Datagrip?
У меня есть файл в формате sql. При простом переносе файла в проект, он открывается, но зашифрован( много непонятных символов и почти никакой информации). Через ssh тоже пробовал заходить, пишет ошибку: Cannot connect to remote host: Server closed connection during identifycation exchange. Что ещё можно попробовать?

Указать кодировку? Encoding
